# How do I install Ubuntu 16.04 on a new drive, and transfer the data from my old drive running Linux Mint 18?

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a 1TB HDD with Linux Mint 18 installed. I am getting a 240GB SSD soon. I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on it, transfer the data I have on the 1TB HDD, and then wipe the 1TB HDD afterwards.

Are there any good tools for this in Ubuntu/Debian?

Comment: Notebook? Desktop? Got an external casing perhaps? Problem seems more hardware related to me and not specific to Ubuntu (ie. the OS). -a- method: store the contents of the HDD in the cloud (google drive). Or just install Ubuntu on the SSD and add the HDD as a 2nd partition.

Comment: Desktop. But wouldn't the HDD have issues since it has Mint on there already?

Comment: No why? add in the disk as an 2nd one and copy/paste what you need and then delete what you dont need.

Comment: Like Rinzwind said, boot from the 16.04 SSD, then mount the 1TB as a non-booting (data) disk, then copy over whatever you wish to keep. Bring a sandwich - 200GB may take a while, depending upon your hardware.